# Select data from database and filter it

Tags: php, sql, double

I would like to fetch data from my database without getting double entries.

Databasestructure:
`id|name|password|location`

These are the values in my database:

1. `1|philip|xyz|New York`
2. `2|marvin|123|London`
3. `3|Robin|zyx|New York`

In return I'd like to get an array of
`array (2) { [0] => New York, [1] => London }`

I dont need New York twice. Is there an SQL-Statement for that?

Philip

Comment: You can also use `DISTINCT` apart from `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2):

Use SELECT DISTINCT (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp):

```
select distinct location from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `group by` clause

```
select location
from tab
group by location
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply interested in the distinct list of locations you can use the distinct keyword:

```
select distinct location
from table
where foo = 'bar'
```

However, you can also use aggregate functions if you're looking for counts, sums or concatenation of information in reference to each location using `group by location`